# Form_for path @get_quote vs @get_quotes (undefined method)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, form-for

Why is the form looking for get_quotes path when I used get_quote? How do I correct the error?

## Rake Route

```
get_quote_index GET    /get_quote(.:format)          get_quote#index
```

## Error:

```
undefined method `get_quotes_path'
```

## Code:

```
<%= form_for( @get_quote ,:html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire result you get when running `rake routes CONTROLLER=get_quote` ? The answer might be in there.

Comment: I think, you did not define get_quote_index as POST.

Comment: What is get_quote? Is it an unsaved active record object?

Comment: The issue was with the naming convention.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the `@get_quote` variable, it's the path.

---

## Solution

You should be using the [`resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web) directive in your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :get_quotes, path: "get_quote" #-> url.com/get_quote/new
```

... this will create a series of RESTful routes that your application will use.

Due to Rails' [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), many helper methods, including [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) are designed to use the `resources` directive above.